# The application behaves strangely-different versions of android

Tags: android

The application behaves strangely in different versions of android
This is the correct view:

```
http://shrani.si/f/1b/Ng/20a9K5H6/cool.png
```

This is the incorrect view:

```
http://shrani.si/f/3A/tJ/FQNPrZA/notcool.png
```

Here is the main.xml where I define the main layouts:

```
[st.koda]

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#646464"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_weight="0.94" >

        <aa.bb.cc.Panel
            android:id="@+id/yourID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="412dp" />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>

[/st.koda]
```

Here is the declaration of onCreate method:

```
[st.koda]
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                mPanel = (Panel) findViewById(R.id.yourID);
[/st.koda]
```

Comment: I think the notcool one looks cooler :P

Comment: ha ha ha legend lol but i cant saw what i draw ;(